# "All host(s) tried for query failed" Error

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

My Java code is as follows:

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Metadata;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

public class CustomerController {

    public void execute() {
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoints("172.16.11.126", "172.16.11.130")
                .withPort(9042)
                .build();
        Session session = cluster.connect();
        String command = "drop keyspace if exists bookstore";
        session.execute(command);
        cluster.close();
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All
>   host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /172.16.11.130
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/172.16.11.130] Cannot
>   connect), /172.16.11.126 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException:
>       [/172.16.11.126] Cannot connect))
>   at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:195)
>   at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:78)
>   at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1029)
>   at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:120)
>   at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:197)
>   at com.pragatisoftware.datastax99.app.CustomerController.execute(CustomerController.java:12)
>   at com.pragatisoftware.datastax99.app.Application.run(Application.java:10)
>   at com.pragatisoftware.datastax99.app.Application.main(Application.java:6)

Environment information:

- Ubuntu machine
- Eclipse Luna
- Java 1.7
- Cassandra 2.0.11

In cassandra.yaml:

```
native_transport_port: 9042
```

Cassandra is running on both the IP addresses provided above (172.16.11.130 and 172.16.11.126) and I am able to connect using CQLSH to both the machines.

By the way, the same code (with the appropriate IP address) worked on a Windows machine, using Cassandra 2.0.9.

Comment: What is you `cassandra.yaml` ? Particularly `rpc_address`

Comment: Also make sure ``start_native_transport: true`` in your yaml file.

Comment: @Chiron, rpc_address was localhost. Changing that to 0.0.0.0 worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change  rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
        broadcast_rpc_address: 1.2.3.4 (Should not be 0.0.0.0) .
for Cassandra version 2.1.10

Also for any further issue  read cassandra.yaml file . lot of things are  self explanatory.