# ECONNREFUSED connecting to remote Cassandra db with node.js

Tags: node.js, express, cassandra, datastax, datastax-startup

I'm using express-cassandra version 0.5.4 to connect to my hosted aws cassandra db. I am authorized to access, but no matter what I change I'm getting ECONNREFUSED

Here is the snippet for express-cassandra that's connecting, which is pretty standard right from the docs.

`models.setDirectory(__dirname + '/../models').bind({
    clientOptions: {
        contactPoints: [process.env.Cluster1Pub,process.env.Cluster2Pub,process.env.Cluster3Pub],
        protocolOptions: {port: 9042},
        keyspace: process.env.keyspace
    },
    ormOptions: {
        defaultReplicationStrategy : {
            class: 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
            replication_factor: 3
        },
        dropTableOnSchemaChange: false,
        dontCreateKeyspace: true
    }
    },function(err) {
        if(err) console.log(err.message);
        else console.log(models.timeuuid());
});`

Comment: This is a pretty common network error when trying to connect to an unopened port. Have you verified that you can hit that port from your client machine? (`nc -z process.env.Cluster1Pub 9042`, for example)

Comment: I tried nc -vz ip port (just z didn't show anything) and I got connection refused. On aws I have it set to accept my ip with all traffic and all ports.

Comment: if you can't netcat or telnet to the port you have a firewall problem. Check both the OS firewall and the AWS firewall.

Comment: is DSE running? can you hit cqlsh locally?

Comment: It's a remote db, I just tried deploying the server and trying it out there but I have the same issue. What's DSE?

Comment: With `NetworkTopologyStrategy` you need the name of the Data Center (i.e. `DC1`) to define the replication factor as in: `DC1: 3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these settings

Change rpc_address: 0.0.0.0 
broadcast_rpc_address: 1.2.3.4

Reference: ["All host(s) tried for query failed" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795479/all-hosts-tried-for-query-failed-error)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to a Cassandra database sitting inside a docker container. Please expose the port when creating your database container using...

```
docker run -d -it -p 9042:9042 -p 9041:9041 --name <container_name> <docker_image_id>
```

After you have exposed the database port, then you can not connect with the database using the nodejs cassandra-driver using...

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');

const client = new cassandra.Client({
  contactPoints: ['h1', 'h2'],
  localDataCenter: 'datacenter1',
  keyspace: 'ks1'
});

const query = 'SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE key = ?';

client.execute(query, [ 'someone' ])
  .then(result => console.log('User with email %s', result.rows[0].email));
```